# Javascript - page reload script won't work

Tags: javascript, redirect, timer

I'm a complete newb to javascript, and much of this code was pulled from other sites. I'm trying to use two things I found to make a page redirect after the user is inactive for a specified amount of time.

I was able to get the timer working and make the page reload instead of redirecting, but my redirect code doesn't work for some reason.

EDIT: forgot to mention this code needs to work for specific pages, as I will be using one page to redirect to a specific page, and another to a different page.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  


var idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 10000); // 10 seconds

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});
 function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
     if ((idleTime > 0) && (window.location.pathname == '/wp'))  { // 10 seconds
       window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
    }
 
}

  });
```

Comment: when you say "won't work" or "my redirect code doesn't work for some reason" you need to explain what isn't working. Is something unexpected happening? is nothing at all happening? etc...

Comment: The idle timer works fine, until I add the stipulation of it needing to be on a specific page as shown with  && (window.location.pathname == '/wp')

Answer (score -1):

I tried you code, it works, but wrong. If it don't work for you - remove that `&& (window.location.pathname == '/wp')` and try again. You have bigger problem, your code just redirects after 10 seconds no matter what. You need to replace to something like that:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  


var idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 second

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});
 function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
     if ((idleTime > 9) && (window.location.pathname == '/wp'))  { // 10 seconds
       window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
    }
 
}

  });
```

Comment: The only change here I see is changing the milliseconds before redirect and adjusting the idle time threshold. I've tried it both ways. Please correct me if I am missing anything.

Comment: In your code idleTime always be more than zero, because you did increment right before check, so redirect will be proceeds each time.